# can I use wit.ai for non-facebook bots?

Tags: wit.ai

I know wit.ai is actually facebook, so is there an option to use this NLP with a non facebook messenger bot?
I would like to use it in many messages channels ON TOP of facebook messenger...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it in any channels you want. See the http reference https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526, so now everything is now just http requests and thus you can call the api from anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is an API and you can use it everywhere.